# How to predict the value's range by machine learning regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have some historical data  about the everyday transaction of cars now. I can use machine learning algorithms to predict the number of transaction next day.But if I want to predict the range(including upper limit and lower limit ) of transaction in next day, how to do it? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're probably looking for confidence intervals, or, more specifically, prediction intervals.

Comment: thanks, etov. I know the concept of 'prediction intervals', but I haven't  perceived it can associate  with machine learning algorithms before. I will try it.

Comment: Oh, I see. So an easy path would be to preform prediction using regression methods - then confidence and prediction intervals come naturally. Other methods may have their own ways (e.g. see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49750/how-do-i-calculate-prediction-intervals-for-random-forest-predictions). When using other machine-learning methods, a quite general method I can suggest is bootstrapping.

Comment: @etov you are sooo nice, thanks.:)